# Memory management when using GPU in TensorFlow

Tags: memory, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

I have some doubts about using GPU in Tensorflow. I was following convolutional neural network tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn) (tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py). As in the tutorial, all parameters (e.g., weights) are stored and updated in CPU memory and GPUs are only used to compute gradients or inference.

Since the weights are stored in CPU, they should be synchronized every iteration and it seems that GPU is underutilized (about 60% according to `nvidia-smi`). In case of using multiple GPUs, I understand that weights should be stored in CPU memory to synchronize between the GPUs. However, why does this tutorial store all weights in CPU even in single GPU? Is there any way to store and update them in GPU memory?

In case of inference, does the weights copied to GPU once and reuse them? or should they copied every time they are used?

How about image data? It seems that those data reside in GPU (not sure). When does this data transferred to GPU? When they are loaded from disk? or when they are required in the GPU?

- If they are copied to GPU right after they are loaded from disk, what happens if size of the image data is too large to fit in the GPU memory? In such case, there is any way to copy data separately (something like prefetching)?
- If they are copied to GPU on demand, is there any way to prefetch them before they are actually used by GPU to avoid idle time?

**EDIT:** It would be helpful if there is any way to check where the send/recv nodes are inserted between CPU and GPU (as in the [white paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/45166.pdf)).

Comment: You can use a queue to fetch data into the GPU. It will be copied when the computation proceeds and there is threaded code to keep it full.

Answer (score 2):

Those tutorials are meant to show off the API, so they don't optimize for performance. It's faster to keep variable on GPU for single tower model, and also faster for multi-tower model when you have p2p communication enabled between GPU. To pin variables to GPU, use the same `tf.device('/gpu:0')` approach as for any other op.

You can see all the memory copies between GPUs if you enable partition graphs, ie do something like this:

```
metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
sess.run(x, options=tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE,
                                  output_partition_graphs=True),
         run_metadata=metadata)

timeline = Timeline(metadata.step_stats)
with open("dynamic_stitch_gpu_profile.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(timeline.generate_chrome_trace_format())
with open("dynamic_stitch_gpu_profile.pbtxt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(metadata))
```

See this issue for an example of using this technique to track down copies:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7251#issuecomment-277385212

For prefetching to GPU, see this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5722)

There are new `stage_op` ops that have been added that allow prefetching to GPU and are dramatically faster than using Python queue runner approach. They are in process of being documented.

Comment: The p2p communication means something like GPUDirect right? Then how can I utilize it in TensorFlow? Does TF auotomatically use GPUDirect if my GPU supports it?

Comment: it usually means GPUs that are on the same PCI-root complex. It's used automatically when available, you will see the p2p matrix printed when you first start GPU

Comment: In the timeline, what does each row means? I can see rows with /gpu:0/memcpy Compute] or /gpu:0/stream:XX Compute or /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 Compute or /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 Compute. Some stream rows and localhost/gpu row contains layers such as conv2D, relu, or add, mul. However their timelines are pretty different.

Comment: I'm not sure actually, I would suggest following the trail of crumbs from `generate_chrome_trace_format` and posting your findings -- https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4172ca2cd7ac34be67bda2600944d284e8907b95/tensorflow/python/client/timeline.py#L620